# Where is GitLab installed on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, gitlab

GitLab was installed by following instructions at https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/ on Ubuntu Server 14.04 but I can't find the install directory. It's commonly said to be in `/home/git/` or `/home/gitlab/` but neither exist.

I need to find the install directory so I can setup SMTP  (RE https://gist.github.com/petermanser/6117494) and migrate existing repositories into GitLab.

Does anyone know where GitLab would be installed on Ubuntu Server 14.04 if not `/home/git/` or `/home/gitlab/`?

Comment: try in your terminal `cat /etc/passwd | grep git` it should have the homedir for that user

Comment: According to the download page you've provided, the configuration files should be in `/etc/gitlab`. Data is stored in `/var/opt/gitlab`.

Comment: In the downloads page there is a link pointing to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

There is all you need to know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Config files are in `etc/gitlab`
- Data is stored in `/var/opt/gitlab`

Thanks to Bjorn for finding the locations and Pavel S for providing `cat /etc/passwd | grep git` for finding the home directory of a given user!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `:)` Where did you find this anyway?

Answer (score 4):

To find a user's home directory do

```
$ cd ~git
```

you will be in that users directory.
:D

Answer (score 3):

There is a **Directory structure** section in the official [README.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md) file of [Omnibus-GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab) repo:

> ***Omnibus-gitlab*** uses four different directories.
>
> - `/opt/gitlab` holds application code for GitLab and its dependencies.
> - `/var/opt/gitlab` holds application data and configuration files that
>     `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` writes to.
> - `/var/log/gitlab` contains all log data generated by components of
>     omnibus-gitlab.
> - `/etc/gitlab` holds configuration files for omnibus-gitlab. These are
>     the only files that you should ever have to edit manually.

---

**But**, if you install the GitLab alone from source (rarely, but useful for unsupported systems like *BSD). Then the GitLab installation location will be different, and it is described in [this official doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/structure.html).